# Close mobile menu by clicking outside of it - body

Tags: jquery

I desperately need your valuable help to make the mobile menu on Helix II framework to close when clicking outside of the drop-down menu or hamburger icon.

My HTML code:

```
<div class="body-innerwrapper">
    <a class="hidden-desktop btn btn-inverse sp-main-menu-toggler collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
    <i class="icon-align-justify"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="hidden-desktop sp-mobile-menu nav-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
    <ul class="">
    <li class="menu-item active first"><a href="#" class="menu-item active first"><span class="menu"><span class="menu-title">Home</span></span></a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="menu-item"><span class="menu"><span class="menu-title">List </span></span></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

My CSS Code when drop-down is visible:

```
.nav-collapse.collapse {
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
}
.collapse.in {
    height: auto;
}
.sp-mobile-menu {
    top: 105px;
    z-index: 999;
}
.sp-mobile-menu {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 90px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.hidden-desktop {
    display: none!important;
}
.collapse {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: height .35s ease;
    -moz-transition: height .35s ease;
    -o-transition: height .35s ease;
    transition: height .35s ease;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is your attempt to do what you want to achieve?

Comment: Please take a quick look on the template here : [link](http://demo.joomshaper.com/2014/travelkit). The mobile menu from this template not closing if i click outside the drop-down menu and if i click on the hamburger icon the previously collapsed <li> elements not closing. Instead if you click on the hamburger icon again the <li> elements are still open from the previous clicks on them. @muecas